# Why the character is falling down when adding to it a movement controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a screenshot of the character components in the inspector.

There is : Animator, Character Controller and the script I created Third Person Movement :

[image: Character]

And the script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 6f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if(direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            controller.Move(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to add a Rigidbody component to the character but he keep falling right when running the game.
If I disable the Character Controller or in the animator unchecking the Apply Root Motion then the character will not fall down but I need this components and settings I think.

Comment: not sure I understand your question, is it possible you cold explain in bit more to understand situation and the problem you having?

Comment: @coder_b The player when I'm running the game he is falling down straight down. Even if he stand on a plane or terrain he just fall down through nonstop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a Rigidbody is falling down because of the gravity. If you don't want the gravity you can uncheck it in the inspector.

If you want to work with gravity then add a collider to the player (based on your character form) and make sure that "is trigger" is not checked. Then add a collider and a Rigidbody without gravity on the plane and the player will just collide with it and it will be able to jump and move without problems :)